# Wordpress dynamic_sidebar() displaying unnecessary value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress dynamic sidebar.

```
               <h2 style="text-align:center; ">
                    <?php //echo dynamic_sidebar('callus'); ?>
                    <?php echo dynamic_sidebar('callus'); ?>
                </h2>
```

and the function is displaying everything ok but displaying a "1" at the bottom of the sidebar text. I searched a lot but couldnot debug. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a problem with a Wordpress function, always [check it in codex first](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) (*Hint:* In Google enter `codex` followed by a space and paste the wordpress function name in there, this normally brings up the right page):

> **Usage**
>
> ```
>  <?php dynamic_sidebar( $index ); ?>
> ```
>
> **Return Value** (boolean)
>
> True, if widget sidebar was found and called. False if not found or not called.

As you can see, do not `echo`. The function itself already takes care of the output. If the function now returns, let's say `true`, echo will additionally output `1` (boolean `true` to string conversion, `echo` is string context).

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; ">
    <?php echo dynamic_sidebar('callus'); ?>
          ^^^^
</h2>
```

This `echo` is not needed. Instead:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; ">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('callus'); ?>
</h2>
```